# I can't get my background image properly linked on my webpage. what am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css

My webpage is currently set up as following:

- Documents/Portfolio/Index.html
- Documents/Portfolio/CSS/Main.css
- Documents/Portfolio/Assets/images/mountains.jpg

In my CSS:

```
background-image: url('../Assets/images/mountains.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
           color: #fff;
```

Sorry for the noob question, but I can't figure this one out. I tried several things and moving the photo around and still no luck.

Answer (score 3):

You are providing too much data to the `background-image` property, replace it with the `background` property.

Comment: You're welcome, then kindly mark this as the correct answer :)